# Query runs but returns first row greater than the DATE at 00:00:00 not the row after 10:00:00

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, worksheet-function, google-sheets-dates

Trying to use the following query:

`=query(WABrdg729!A:B, "select A, B where A > date '"&text(datevalue($A$6), "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND A > timeofday '"&text(timevalue($A$6), "hh:mm:ss")&"' limit 1")`

Query runs but returns first row greater than the DATE at 00:00:00 not the row after 10:00:00.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18q5Y3tq0wuAeZ7aGNQy3c3jrV-pUAuKXG-Tw5bYGTI4/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet Date/Time Demo, cell E6, querying sheet WABrdg729

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use `datetime` in the select vs. separate date and time specs.
See linked sheets.
Revised query is:

```
="select A, B where A > datetime '"&text(datevalue($A$6), "yyyy-mm-dd")&" " &text(timevalue($A$6), "hh:mm:ss")&"' limit 1"
```

Could not find documentation for the query argument spec of `date`, `timeofday`, `datetime`. Just guessed and it worked.

Comment: Instead of `datetime` you can also use `timestamp`. For more info about the query arguments you can visit the [Query Language Reference (Version 0.7)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#reserved-words)